# Finding the minimum pixel in an array

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl

I am trying to reduce an arbitrary texture of X by X to 2 by X in XNA.
I try running this code:

```
int x;
int y;
float2 minim={1,1};
float2 current;
if(coords.x==0)
{
    for(x=0;x<=range/2;x=x+1)
    {
        coords.x=x;
        current=tex2D(input,coords);
        minim=min(minim,current);       
    }
}
if(coords.x==1)
{
    for(x=range/2;x<=range;x++)
    {
        coords.x=x;
        current=tex2D(input,coords);
        minim=min(minim,current);       
    }
}
return float4(minim,0,1);
```

I hit all sorts of problems when trying to compile like "Unable to unroll loop" and "Can't use gradients in loops with break".

**First question**: Am I on the right road by trying to calculate that in a single shader pass or I should reduce it by smaller steps by ping-ponging the date between RenderTargets?

**Second question**: If the idea is right, what is wrong then with my code?

Comment: Basically you're very much *not* on the right track. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve in more detail? (Perhaps ask a fresh question?)

Answer (score 0):

**Second question:** whatever you want to do with that shader... The complier is saying that it can not *unroll the loop*s because it doesn't know the value of 'range' at compile time. Probably your shader model version requieres to have a compile-time constant iteration count, eg. you are not allowed to have dynamic variables in the 'for'-condition.

**First question:** You surely can do what you ask in words in one pass, but the shader chunk is so out of context, that i cant answer question 1...

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored options other than use of a shader to achieve this?

Off the top of my head:

1) When drawing this texture, give the source rectangle a width of 2 and height X, thus only drawing 2 by X instead of X by X.

2) Make use of the GetData and SetData to extract the 2 by X portion of the texture you wish to use.